# Subalgebras of $C_b(X)$ whose elements do not vanish simultaneously at any point

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a completely regular space. How  can I find all   Banach subalgebras of $C_b(X)$ (all complex-valued bounded continuous functions on $X$) with the property that for every $x\in X$ there exists an element of Banach subalgebra that is nonzero at $x$?

Comment: Maybe it will help to know that $C_b(X) \cong C(\beta X)$, where $\beta X$ is the [Stone–Čech compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of $X$. Since $X$ is completely regular, the inclusion $X \to \beta X$ is a homeomorphism whose image is dense in $\beta X$.

Comment: In general this will be difficult (intractable?), even if $X$ is compact. Think for instance about the disc algebra and its relatives. Can you classify all such subalgebras if $X=\overline{\mathbb{D}}$?

Comment: Thank you Mr Tomek Kania. but it is not useful for me.